# r shiny: How do I save a model object in one reactive function to be used in another?

Tags: r, shiny

I have made an machine learning application that will train a randomforest model on some uploaded data, and give a prediction of a specified single obsevation based on some selected `inputs widgets`, once an `actionbutton()` is pressed.

Both the function for training of the model "`randomForest()`" and function for prediction "`predict()`" is run, everytime the `actionbutton()` is pressed.

I have come to realize that this is not very effecient use of the computational power, since the `randomForest()` function usually does not need to be run more than once, and can take a while to run depending on the size of the uploaded dataset and model specifications.

To fix this issue, I have create another `actionbutton()` which sole purpose is to train the model, so it dont have to be retrained everytime I want to make a prediction. Once a model is trained, it is saved as a 'model object'.

The `predict()` function requires a 'model object' as an input, which is where the problem arise. I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the 'model object' in such a way that the prediction function can accept it as an input.

This is how I create the model object by the press of an `actionbutton`:

```
model <- observeEvent(input$trainmodel,{
              df <- selected_df()
              model <- randomForest(eval(parse(text=paste(names(df)[1],"~ ."))), data = df, ntree = 500, mtry = 5, importance = TRUE)
          })
```

And this is roughly how I refer to the 'model object' in the `reactive()` code chunk of the `predict()` function.

```
model <- model()
Prediction <- predict(model,test)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as I get the error message:

> Warning: Error in model: could not find function "model"

Keep in mind that all of this works if I define the 'model object' inside the `reactive()` bracket, but this would ofcourse cause the very problem I was trying to fix in the first place.

So my question is:

**How do I specify the model object, so it can be used in other functions such as** `predict()`?

------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

Is it possible that the problem is caused by the fact that both the dataframe and the model object is defined in the `model()` functionen?
-If so, how do I fix that? I need the dataframe defined to train the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try `eventReactive` instead and make sure you return the object at the end

```
model <- eventReactive(input$trainmodel,{
  req(selected_df())
  df <- selected_df()
  randomForest(eval(parse(text=paste(names(df)[1],"~ ."))), data = df, ntree = 500, mtry = 5, importance = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: By return, do you mean using `model()` or the `return()` function?

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is in the fact that I specify both a dataframe object and a model object in the `eventReactive()`?